# would the unity2D (c#) read useless "if" structures?

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I just want to know if my useless if-statements effect on my rendering time or not ? I am making an unity2D game and in `update` method I have used some if-statements that their conditions may go `true` once a minute but this method updates every frame.

```
void Update(){
for (long i = 0; i< 100000000000000; i++)
{
    if (i == 999)
    {
        "lots of functions"
    }
}
}
```

Does it ignore the rest of `if` when the condition is not true?
my question is if the condition of "if-statement" is not `true`, would the functions of "if-statement" effect on rendering ? Or will they be just ignored when their conditions are `false`?

Comment: What do you mean by "will the compiler ignore"? All code in a source file must have valid syntax, if that's what you mean.

Comment: No the compiler will not ignore the if statement it will compile it.

Comment: The compiler compiles the code only once.  The .Net CLR will run a loop 1000000 times if needed. The two components are distinct.

Comment: thank you all but my question is if the condition of "if-statement" is not true, would the functions of "if-statement" effect on rendering ? or they just being ignored when their conditions are false?

Comment: I hope to all that is good and fluffy that you're not actually using that code, or anything similar, over the likes of: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html InvokeRepeating

Answer (score 0):

The body of the `if` statement will not execute, and will be ignored, if the statement is false.

If you are so concerned with holding up execution with so many iterations, i advise you to use a `while` loop inside of an `IEnumerator` as so:

```
IEnumerator DoLoop(){
    long i = 0;

    while (i< 100000000000000)
    {
        if (i == 999)
        {
            "lots of functions"
        }

        i++;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

This way, other things are allowed to be executed at the same time as your loop is running.

Answer (score 0):

The condition (such as `i == 999`) will be evaluated every time the `if` statement is reached (that is, every frame), but the nested statements (`"lots of functions"`) will only execute (and only take rendering time) when the condition is true. That's the whole point of an `if` statement.